# How to search an element of an object in an arraylist (Java) and if it exists, print the .toString of that object

Tags: java, object, search, arraylist, element

In this particular program that I am trying to create I want the user to be able to create a new object with different elements (string, int, boolean), and then store it in an ArrayList, similar to most Book/Library projects.
To do that I have created a class called Game where I created a constructor, setters/getters as well as a .toString method. 
In the mainmenu class, I have also created some switch statements to provide the user with different choices based on what they want to do.
Here is where I request the user to provide the fields for the new game that they want to store
*as pointed out I forgot to mention that I have created an ArrayList named storage*

```
ArrayList <Game> storage = new ArrayList <Game> ();
```

```
private void gameInsert() 
    {
        String title;
        String desc;
        int date;
        String quality;
        Boolean given;  //(similar to the ones created in the game class)

        for (int index = 0; index < 1; index++) 
        {
        System.out.println("Please enter a title: ");
        title = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("Please enter the genre: ");
        desc = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the year of release: ");
        date = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Please enter the quality of the product");
        System.out.println("NC = new condition, MC= Mint condition, BC = Barely Used , U = Used ");
        quality = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("Is the item borrwed to someone? ");
        System.out.println("Press 1 = Yes | Press 2 = No");
        if ( Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine()) == 1) 
        {
            given = true;
        }
        else
            given = false;
        volume ++;
        storage.add(new Game(title, desc, date, quality, given ));
        }
```

After that I wanted the user to be able to search through this arrayList by providing a title and find all the available information for the game that has the same title

```
private void gameSearch() 
    {

        System.out.println("Enter the game's title!: ");
        String search_title = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        for (int i= 0; i <storage.size(); i++) 
        if(storage.equals(search_title)) 
        {
            System.out.println("The game was found!");
            // print the .toString for this particular object;
            // or print by using the getters of the game class.
           // example given: title: ----
           //                genre: ---- etc.
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("I am sorry, game not found. Please try again.");
        }
```

I know that my gameSearch function does not work but that is as far as I was able to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `storage` is the name given to the list of `Game` objects. If that's the case, `storage.equals()` couldn't work since you want a particular object in the list to equal search_title, not the whole list. You can accomplish what you want by doing this:

```
for (Game game:storage) {
  if game.getTitle().equals(search_title) {
    System.out.println("The game was found!");
  }
}
```

However, if I were you I wouldn't use a list at all. I would use a Map instead. Create a Map instead of a list:

```
Map<String, Game> storage = new HashMap<>();
```

Put into the Map instead of adding into the list:

```
storage.put(title, new Game(title, desc, date, quality, given ));
```

Then just search the Map by the key:

```
Game found = storage.get(title);
```

Comment: Oh I know it would a lot easier with Maps. I have a basic understanding around them but we haven't been taught about them in this course yet, thus I did not use it. I suppose after that, I could use the same function so that the user could search for the title and then use the setters to make changes on this particular object?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void gameSearch() {
        boolean foundGame = false;
        System.out.println("Enter the game's title!: ");
        String search_title = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < storage.size(); i++) {
            Storage storage = storage.get(i);
            if (storage.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(search_title)) {
                System.out.println("The game was found!");
                // print the .toString for this particular object;
                // or print by using the getters of the game class.
                // example given: title: ----
                // genre: ---- etc.
                foundGame = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!foundGame){
            System.out.println("I am sorry, game not found. Please try again.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this list of games:

```
List<Game> storage = List.of(
    new Game("My game title 1", "short description", 2019, "U", false),
    new Game("My game title 2", "short description", 2019, "U", false),
    new Game("My game title 3", "short description", 2019, "U", false),
    new Game("My game title 4", "short description", 2019, "U", false)
);
```

And you are looking for `My game title 3`:

```
String searchTitle = "My game title 3";
```

You search function is:

```
String result = storage.stream()
    .filter(game -> game.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(searchTitle))
    .map(Object::toString)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse("I am sorry, game not found. Please try again.");
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Indeed, it does work! Unfortunately, we have not been taught how to use the filter/stream yet. But glad to see there are many ways to approach this :)